# create left and right data sets from one table

Tags: sql

I have a data set where the rows can be joined to each other by a field in common on each row called **link_identifier**. If you include the value of **data_origin_type** you should be able to define the LEFT of a join and the right based upon this second field's value.

Here's the code I'm trying but its not working, maybe it makes more sense than my description above.

```
SELECT TOP 100 recs.security_name
        ,local_party.position_value AS LP
        ,counter_party.position_value AS CP

FROM [C3_CoreRex_Default].[dbo].[r_L0_NAV_Positions] AS recs

     LEFT JOIN
       [C3_CoreRex_Default].[dbo].[r_L0_NAV_Positions] AS counter_party
     ON recs.link_identifier = counter_party.link_identifier
     AND counter_party.data_origin_type = 'Cpty'

     RIGHT JOIN
       [C3_CoreRex_Default].[dbo].[r_L0_NAV_Positions] AS local_party
     ON recs.link_identifier = local_party.link_identifier
     AND local_party.data_origin_type = 'Local'
```

Here's example data:

```
link_identifier    data_origin_type    security_name    position_value
123                Local               ABC Security     175
123                Cpty                ABC Security     180
```

My expected Result is:

```
security_name    LP    CP

ABC Security     175   180
```

Thanks, Matt

Comment: thanks @mkRabbani for editing table data - I'd like to know how to do what you managed to do. Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite understand on your requirements. But based on your expected result, what you'll need is a distinct and 2 left joins.

Let me know if this is what you looking for:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 recs.security_name
    ,local_party.position_value AS LP
    ,counter_party.position_value AS CP
FROM [C3_CoreRex_Default].[dbo].[r_L0_NAV_Positions] AS recs
LEFT JOIN [C3_CoreRex_Default].[dbo].[r_L0_NAV_Positions] AS counter_party ON recs.link_identifier = counter_party.link_identifier
    AND counter_party.data_origin_type = 'Cpty'
LEFT JOIN [C3_CoreRex_Default].[dbo].[r_L0_NAV_Positions] AS local_party ON recs.link_identifier = local_party.link_identifier
    AND local_party.data_origin_type = 'Local'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this following syntax. This will SUM your LP and CP value per security_name and results will be shown in one row per security_name.

```
SELECT security_name,
SUM(CASE WHEN data_origin_type = 'Local' THEN position_value ELSE 0 END) LP,
SUM(CASE WHEN data_origin_type = 'Cpty' THEN position_value ELSE 0 END) CP
FROM your_table
GROUP BY security_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses, much appreciated. After playing with it a little more, I decided on the following solution however, it might not perform as well as I had hoped but it does work. I thought I would share it

```
WITH loc_pty AS (
    SELECT SUM(lpy.position_value) AS loc_position
   ,lpy.link_identifier
   ,lpy.security_name
   ,lpy.link_status
    FROM [C3_CoreRex_Default].[dbo].[r_L0_NAV_Positions] AS lpy
         WHERE lpy.data_origin_type = 'Local'
    GROUP BY lpy.security_name
            ,lpy.link_identifier
            ,lpy.reconciliation_identifier
            ,lpy.link_status
                ),
    cnt_pty AS (
    SELECT SUM(cpy.position_value) AS cpy_position
  ,cpy.link_identifier
  ,cpy.security_name
   FROM [C3_CoreRex_Default].[dbo].[r_L0_NAV_Positions] AS cpy
        WHERE cpy.data_origin_type = 'Cpty'
   GROUP BY cpy.security_name
           ,cpy.link_identifier
           ,cpy.reconciliation_identifier
               )
SELECT *
FROM loc_pty
JOIN cnt_pty ON loc_pty.link_identifier = cnt_pty.link_identifier
```

The problem I was having was to have two entirely separate data sets, then join them, then apply groupings and calculations on them. Thanks, Matt